# How to add iAd in app

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I want to add iAd in my app. And i have done lot of research and seen video that display how to add iAd in your project. But all video and tutorial display code for adding iAd in project none of them said any thing about if we have to do something in iTunes connect or not.

I have seen this link in [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/). which is nice to add iAd. and in that link it will display tab `iTunes Connect Developer Guide` which display some setting we do have to make in iTunes connect to add iAd in app.

So as my understanding we have to first do that setting in iTunes connect account for iAd and then implement code to add iAd in project.

But i m confuse at this line in apple doc `After you have enabled at least one app for iAd ads, you see the iAd Network module on your iTunes Connect homepage.` What does it mean that enable app for iAd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to itunes connect -> manage your apps and pick the app you want, then click on Set Up iAd Network, just that.

> But i m confuse at this line in apple doc After you have enabled at least one app for iAd ads, you see the iAd Network module on your iTunes Connect homepage. What does it mean that enable app for iAd?

This means, when you activate iAd (as I told you), a new module appears called iAd Network, and there you can see the statistics (impresions, revenue, etc)

Comment: So now step will be first, set up iAd contract. Second, implement iAd code in my project. Third, enable app for iAd in to  manage your apps  section . Wright, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The first step is set up the iAd contract, but I don't think order matters in the other 2 steps, because you have to do both of them to get it working

Comment: On itunes connect main menu. It appears after you activate iAd in at least one of your apps

Comment: And you should have signed the "iAd App Network" contract on "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" section too

Comment: There is nothing in itunesconnect in the app settings to enable ads. There is only the contract for all apps.

Comment: There was an option 2 years ago, things change, but thanks for the downvote anyway

Answer (score 5):

[itunesconnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) -> manage your apps

and this code Display the Default Screen of iAd network

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface iAdExViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    ADBannerView *adView;
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;

@end
```

Then modify `viewDidLoad` method in **iAdExViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    adView.delegate=self;

    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    NSLog(@"Banner view is beginning an ad action");
    BOOL shouldExecuteAction = YES;

    if (!willLeave && shouldExecuteAction)
    {
        // stop all interactive processes in the app
        // [video pause];
        // [audio pause];
    }
    return shouldExecuteAction;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    // resume everything you've stopped
    // [video resume];
    // [audio resume];
}
```